# Showing the prototype cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

If I wanted to create a table view in Objective-C with each cell customized differently, I would create multiple prototype cells, customize it, and set each its own identifier. I would then add this code so that the cell would appear exactly how I customized it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    switch ( indexPath.row )
    {
        case 0:
            CellIdentifier = @"fj";
            break;

        case 1:
            CellIdentifier = @"pg";
            break;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

I'm now updating my app to Swift 2 and would like to know how to code above should be changed to work in Swift 2. Thanks!

Comment: The same just in Swift syntax. Additionally you could add Enum for Cell Identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellIdentifier: String

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cellIdentifier = "fj"
    case 1:
        cellIdentifier = "pg"
    default:
        cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

You'll notice the syntax is very similar, and the function calls follow the same format as the Objective-C version. To clean it up a little, like @sunshine mentioned, you could do the cell identifiers as an enum, and have the specific rows stored as instances of that enum in an array. Then your switch is just on the enum value stored at the row index in the array.